# How to get the inverse of this function?

Tags: functions, inverse

I have the function f(x) = (1+8x) / (3-3x).

I have been stuck on trying to get the inverse of this function by isolating for y. I ended up with:

x = (1+8y) / (3-3y) but I am not quite sure where to go from there.

Comment: I see you've switched the roles of $x$ and $y$. Now try to solve the second equation for $y$ and this will be your inverse.

Comment: I have tried to do that but I do not know what to do when there are 2 y's positioned like that.

Comment: Try multiplying by the denominator.

Comment: Your inference about what x is equal to is incorrect @user1804933. You can't just switch y and x like that. You're basically allowed to manipulate an equation by doing almost anything you want (apart from divide by 0, for example) as long as you do the same thing to each side of the equation e.g. multiply by $3-3y$. See my answer for a break down of the steps needed to find the inverse.

Comment: As an aside, you also have to be careful about raising each side to a power: e.g squaring both sides: it can introduce extra solutions and you have to be careful not to miss them, but this is an unusual move and irrelevant in the context of this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ y = \frac{1+8x}{3-3x}$$
$$(3-3x)y = 1+8x$$ (multiplying each side by $3-3x$)
$$8x + 3xy = 3y -1$$ (multiplying out the brackets, adding $3xy$ to each side and subtracting $1$ from each side)
$$x(8+3y) = 3y - 1$$ (taking out a factor of $x$ from LHS)
$$x = \frac{3y-1}{8+3y}$$ (dividing each side by $8+3y$)

Answer (score 1):

I get $x=\frac{4y-1}{3y+8}$. ${}{}$

Comment: Sorry there was a typo and it is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here we start with $$f(x) = \frac{1+8x}{4-3x}$$

So we set $y = f(x)$ and solve for $x$ in terms of $y$:

$$y = \frac{1+8x}{4-3x}$$

$$(4-3x)y = 1+8x$$
$$4y - 3xy = 1+8x$$
$$4y - 3xy - 1 = 8x$$
$$4y - 3xy - 1 - 8x = 0$$
$$-3xy - 1 - 8x = -4y$$
$$-3xy -8x = -4y+1$$
$$-3x(y+8/3) = -4y+1$$
$$-3x = \frac{-4y+1}{y+8/3}$$
$$x = \frac{4y-1}{3y+8}$$

What we have essentially done is find a general equation in terms of $x$ and $y$.  Then, we reverse the process.  Can you see how the general method works?